# Bessel's integral matlab implementation

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to implement this [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel.27s_integrals) of Bessel function of the first kind of order n.

$$J_n(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(n\tau-x\sin(\tau))}d\tau$$

here is what I tried:

```
t = -pi:0.1:pi;
n = 1;
x = 0:5:20;
A = @(t) exp(sqrt(-1)*(n*t-x*sin(t)));
B = integral(A(t),-pi,pi);
plot(A(t),x)
```

the plot i'm trying to get is as shown in the wikipedia page.[image]

it said:

> Error using  *  Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in besselfn (line 8) `A(t) = exp(sqrt(-1)*(n*t-x*sin(t)));`

so i tried putting x=5;

and the output was:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
>
> Error in besselfn (line 8) `A(t) = exp(sqrt(-1)*(n*t-x*sin(t)));`

How to get this correct? what am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you just use [besselj](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/besselj.html)?

Comment: @MattL. I want to know how they implemented it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Matt has said, you have to evaluate the integral for each value of `x` separately, which can be done with a for loop.

And the other remark is that you can have to pass a [function](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#inputarg_fun) as the first argument to the function integral. So instead of `A(t)`, which will evaluate your function at the values you declared for `t` (which always returns the same vector), just use `A` (or `@(t) A(t)`).

One way you could implement this is:

```
n = 0 : 2;
x = linspace(0, 20, 200);

A = @(t, x, n) exp(1i * (n * t - x * sin(t)));
B = zeros(length(n), length(x));

for m = 1 : length(n)
    for k = 1 : length(x)
        B(m,k) = integral(@(t) A(t, x(k), n(m)), -pi, pi);
    end
end

plot(x, B(1,:), 'r', x, B(2,:), 'g--', x, B(3,:), 'b-.')
legend('J_0(x)', 'J_1(x)', 'J_2(x)', 'Location', 'NorthEast')
```

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @AIaye do not that MATLAB will complain about B being complex, if you do not want that you could use the cosine instead of exp (like in Matt's answer). Also the graphs in your question are normalized by a factor 1/(2pi).

Answer (score 2):

You indeed have to use just a single value for the variables `x` and `n` that you pass to your integration function. If you want to evaluate the integral for different values of `x` or `n` you need to loop over these values.

Below is an example using octave (with `quad` instead of `integral`, but I think it should also work in Matlab using `integral`). If you don't understand the use of the function handle below, check out [Parameterizing Using Anonymous Functions](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html).

```
function J = mybesselj(n,x)

J = quad(@(t) cos(n*t-x*sin(t)), -pi, pi) / (2*pi);
```

[Note that I used the function $f(t)=\cos(nt-x\sin(t))$ instead of the complex exponential, because the imaginary part of the integrand $\exp(j(nt-\sin(t)))$ is odd, and, consequently, the integral over the imaginary part vanishes (due to the symmetrical integration limits).]

Now you have to use a loop to compute the Bessel function for a range of values of `x` and `n`:

```
x = linspace(0,20,100);
J0 = zeros(100,1);
J1 = zeros(100,1);
J2 = zeros(100,1);
for i=1:100,
    xi = x(i);
    J0(i) = mybesselj(0,xi);
    J1(i) = mybesselj(1,xi);
    J2(i) = mybesselj(2,xi);
end
plot(x,J0,x,J1,x,J2);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but it is not working fine with matlab!

Comment: @AIaye: Can only be a very minor thing, but anyway, you also got another solution.